# No stacktrace showing in Crashlytics console when Flutter app calls 'recordError'

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics

I am using the Crashlytics method 'recordError' to for a non-fatal error to be sent to crashlytics.

I am grabbing the current stacktrace, and passing it to recordError as follows...

```
StackTrace stacktrace = StackTrace.current;
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError("forced error" , stacktrace);
```

I have used the debugger to inspect the stacktrace, and it has multiple frames present.
When the error arrives in the crashlytics console, it arrives with only a single frame in the stacktrace and it says...

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError
forced error. Error thrown null.
```